# Call set outside of for loop

Tags: apex

I keep getting an error when I am trying to call outside of my For loop. I know that I shouldn't be having the query inside of the for loop. All I am trying to do is take the true condition of the if (if (exisitingPortalEmailSet.contains(a.PersonEmail)) {) and if they find the email address stamp the id on the account level. I keep getting the error 'Variable does not exist: existingPortalEmailSet'. Is there a different way that I should be calling this?

```
// Person Account emails must be kept in sync with the Azure accounts used in the customer Portal
// If an account's email is already used in another Portal Account, update Portal Account relationship on Person Account
// Otherwise, create a Portal Account Transaction to update Azure with the new email
public static void PortalEmailChange(List<Account> oldAcc, List<Account> newAcc, Map<Id, Account> oldAccMap, Map<Id, Account> newAccMap) {
    List<Portal_Account_Transaction__c> patsToInsert = new List<Portal_Account_Transaction__c>();
    List<Account> accsToUpdate = new List<Account>();

    // Building a set of emails from the updated accounts whose emails already have a Portal Account 
    Set<String> portalEmailSet = new Set<String>();
    for (Account a: newAcc) {
        if (a.IsPersonAccount) {
            portalEmailSet.add(a.PersonEmail);
        }
    }
    List<Portal_Account__c> paList = [SELECT Id, Current_Email_Address__c FROM Portal_Account__c WHERE Current_Email_Address__c IN :portalEmailSet];
    Set<String> exisitingPortalEmailSet = new Set<String>();
    for (Portal_Account__c pa: paList) {
        exisitingPortalEmailSet.add(pa.Current_Email_Address__c);
    }

    for (Account a: newAcc) {
        // We only impose restrictions on changing Person Account email addresses when the user has an Azure account
        if (a.IsPersonAccount) {
            if (a.PersonEmail != oldAccMap.get(a.Id).PersonEmail) {
                if (exisitingPortalEmailSet.contains(a.PersonEmail)) {
                    //a.addError('A Portal Account already exists for \''+a.PersonEmail+'\'. Email Address is unique and cannot be the same for two Portal Accounts.');
                    a.Portal_Account__c = exisitingPortalEmailSet.get(pa.id);
                    accsToUpdate.add(a);
                } else if (a.Already_Migrated__c) {
                    Portal_Account_Transaction__c pat = new Portal_Account_Transaction__c(New_Email_Address__c = a.PersonEmail, Portal_Account__c = a.Portal_Account__c, Account__c = a.Id, Old_Email_Address__c = oldAccMap.get(a.Id).PersonEmail);
                    patsToInsert.add(pat);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    try{
        update accsToUpdate;
        insert patsToInsert;
    }catch(Exception e){
        System.debug(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: What error are you getting? Debug log? I must be blind, but I don't see any SOQL in a for-loop. And asking a collection for information inside a loop is perfectly fine.

Comment: I am getting the error 'Compile Error: Variable does not exist: pa at line 94 column 75'. So would I be able to do a SOQL when assigning the a.portal_account__c line? I was always under the impression that a query inside of a For-Loop was always a bad thing to do.

Comment: Which of the lines is 94 in that code, I can only see 42 lines.  And no, you should not execute a SOQL query within a loop. You are already using collections, why would you want to change that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have a bit of a logic issue in there..

at

```
Set<String> exisitingPortalEmailSet = new Set<String>();
for (Portal_Account__c pa: paList) {
    exisitingPortalEmailSet.add(pa.Current_Email_Address__c);
}
```

you are adding just email addresses to a Set, but further down, you apparently want to get the Portal_Account__c object associated with that email address. Here:

```
            if (exisitingPortalEmailSet.contains(a.PersonEmail)) {
                //a.addError('A Portal Account already exists for \''+a.PersonEmail+'\'. Email Address is unique and cannot be the same for two Portal Accounts.');
                // ---- This seems to be your issue -----
                a.Portal_Account__c = exisitingPortalEmailSet.get(pa.id);
                accsToUpdate.add(a);
            } else if ....
```

What you want to do is to store the email address alongside your Portal_Account__c in a Map, so you can find your object again. Change your Set to a Map:

```
Map<String, Portal_Account__c> exisitingPortalEmailSet = new Map<String, Portal_Account__c> ();
for (Portal_Account__c pa: paList) {
    exisitingPortalEmailSet.put(pa.Current_Email_Address__c, pa);
}
```

This way you can retrieve the Portal_Account__c.Id where you need it:

```
        if (exisitingPortalEmailSet.containsKey(a.PersonEmail)) {
            a.Portal_Account__c = exisitingPortalEmailSet.get(a.PersonEmail).Id;
            accsToUpdate.add(a);
        } else if ....
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have a query or DML operation in a loop. There's no need to optimize this code further, as far as I can see.